# Why the calculator crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a calculator as a homework. It looks like to work fine if I gave correct inputs. But if I give the first number to be an empty string, the program crashes:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

```
def read_numbers():
    try:
        number1 = float(input("Give first number: "))
        number2 = float(input("Give the second number: "))
        return [number1,number2]
    except ValueError:
        read_numbers()
    except TypeError:
        read_numbers()

def summa():
    numbers = read_numbers()
    return numbers[0]+numbers[1]

command = ""
while command != "q":
    command = input("Give command: ")
    if command == "s":
        print(summa())
    elif command == "q":
        break
```

Comment: Remember to return the result from calling `read_numbers()` in your exception blocks. And I would really rewrite the code to use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: But as I understood, it would return result if no exception happens. And if it happens, it asks numbers again. Yes, I have to rewrite the code but I would like to understand what is my mistake in the current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `read_numbers()` function doesn't always return anything. When a function ends without a `return` statement, `None` is returned instead. When you recurse (with a `ValueError` or `TypeError`, you forget to return the recursive call result.

You'd return the recursive call like:

```
def read_numbers():
    try:
        number1 = float(input("Give first number: "))
        number2 = float(input("Give the second number: "))
        return [number1,number2]
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return read_numbers()
```

where I combined both exceptions into one handler. Notice the `return` on the `read_numbers()` call; just because a *nested* call returns a value, doesn't mean that the function call itself passes on that result automatically.

But using a loop would be better:

```
def read_numbers():
    while True:
        try:
            number1 = float(input("Give first number: "))
            number2 = float(input("Give the second number: "))
            return [number1,number2]
        except ValueError:
            pass  # continue the loop
```

where the `return` will end the loop as well as the function. I removed the `TypeError` exception, `input()` always returns a string and `float()` will only ever raise `ValueError` when passed a string that cannot be parsed into a floating point number. `TypeError`s are only raised if the argument is of a type that cannot be converted to `float`, such as a dictionary or custom object.

Comment: @JonClements: if this were Python 2 then you never know *what* type is returned by `input()`... but you have a point.